# Problema para fazer upload de imagens via dropzone VUE.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, upload

Sem nenhum motivo aparente meu site está retornando o seguinte erro quando vou fazer upload de uma imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A mensagem diz:

```
DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <style>
        body {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #222;
        font: 16px/1.5 -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .container {
```

Estou usando dropzone no laravel, esse aqui é o arquivo dentro do components:

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <dropzone 
            id="myVueDropzone" 
            ref="myVueDropzone" 
            :url="upload" 
            v-on:vdropzone-success="showSuccess" 
            :max-number-of-files="20"
            :use-custom-dropzone-options="true"
            :dropzone-options="customOptionsObject"
            :max-file-size-in-mb="5">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" v-model="token">
            <input type="hidden" name="images[]" v-model="images">
        </dropzone>

        <div class="thumb-images">
            <draggable v-model="thumbs" @start="drag=true" @end="checkMove">
               <div class="image-box" v-for="(thumb, index) in thumbs" :key="index">
                    <span class="capa" v-if="index == 0">Capa</span>
                    <img class="thumb" :src="thumb">
                    <div class="remove-image-button" v-on:click="removeImage(index)" role="button">
                        <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <title>ic_trash</title>
                            <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
                                <path d="M19 4h-3.5l-1-1h-5l-1 1H5v2h14V4zM6 19c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V7H6v12z" fill="#FFF"></path>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </draggable>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Dropzone from 'vue2-dropzone'
    import draggable from 'vuedraggable'

    export default {

        name: 'vc-dropzone',

        props: ['token', 'upload', 'gallery'],

        components: {
            Dropzone,
            draggable
        },

        data() {
            return {
                drag: false,
                images: [],
                thumbs: [],
                customOptionsObject: {
                    language: {
                        dictDefaultMessage: '<div class="dz-icon icon-wrap icon-circle icon-wrap-md"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-3x"></i></div><div><p class="dz-text">Arraste as imagens aqui</p><p class="text-muted">ou click para selecionar manualmente</p></div>',
                        dictFileTooBig:'Arquivo muito grande. Maximo permitido: 2Mb'

                    }
                }
            }
        },

        methods: {
            'showSuccess': function (file, response) {
                this.images.push(response.image)
                this.thumbs.push('/images/' + response.image)
                $("#images-hidden").val(this.images)
                this.$refs.myVueDropzone.removeFile(file);
            },
            removeImage: function(index) {
                this.thumbs.splice(index, 1)
                this.images.splice(index, 1)
                $("#images-hidden").val(this.images)
            },
            checkMove: function() {
                this.images = [];
                var local = this
                this.thumbs.forEach(function(item, index) {
                    local.images.push(item.replace('/images/', ''))
                })
                $("#images-hidden").val(this.images)
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            if(this.gallery != "") {
                var gallery = this.gallery.split(',')
                var local = this
                this.images = gallery
                gallery.forEach(function(item, index) {
                    // var mockFile = { name: item, size: 12345 };
                    // local.$refs.myVueDropzone.manuallyAddFile(mockFile, '/images/' + item, null, null, local);
                    local.thumbs.push('/images/' + item)
                })
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>
```

Esse problema está impedindo usuários de fazer upload de suas imagens, porém está funcionando normalmente em localhost.

Aqui é aonde chamamos o component na index:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
    <vc-dropzone token="{{ csrf_token() }}" upload="{{ route('upload-anuncio') }}" gallery="{{ $anuncio->gallery->implode('name', ',') }}"></vc-dropzone>
    <input type="hidden" id="images-hidden" name="images" value="{{ old('images', $anuncio->gallery->implode('name', ',')) }}">
</div>
```

Alguém sabe o porque isso está acontecendo? Até alguns dias atrás estava funcionando normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, era um erro na hospedagem, por algum motivo o servidor(Linux) restringiu o acesso na pasta public/images, foi necessário dar um comando para possibilitar alteração de arquivos na mesma. Me pergunto se mais alguém tem acesso ao servidor, afinal, até ontem estava funcionando normalmente...